# Magento 2 - what event should I observe to change/intercept the calculation of subtotals on Cart

Tags: php, xml, magento2

I am using Magento 2.
I made an observer that observes anytime a new item is added to the cart. The observer works properly, I also managed to create a single product discount with this observer, here is the events.xml file:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="PerfectStorm_Pricecalculations_Addtocart" instance="PerfectStorm\Pricecalculations\Observer\PricecalculationsAfterAddtoCart" />
</event>
```

The problem is, I want to do the same in order to change and intercept the calculation of the subtotals in the cart for each item. But I don't know what event should I observe.

Can you please advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this event

```
sales_quote_load_after
```

Or you can reference vendor/magento/module-sales-rule and take a look at

```
vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/etc/sales.xml
```

and

```
vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Quote/Discount.php
```

To see how to Magento native discount works

Thanks